# Reflection through a line

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations, self-learning, reflection

I need to find the matrix of reflection through line $y=- \frac 23 x$ .

I'm trying to visualise a vector satisfying this. The standard algorithm states that we need to find the angle this line makes with $x$ axis and the transformation matrix can be seen as $R_\alpha T_0 R_{-\alpha}.$

I'm not sure how to proceed. I can't visualise the angle it makes with $x$ axis. 
Is there a procedure to think about such reflections?

Comment: Is this in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo It hasn't been specified. It seems like it's in R^2.

Comment: I would think so too, then this question would make sense.

Comment: try writing \mathbb{R} next time and dollar signs around it.

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo Sure! I am not aware of the syntax so I do it in this format. I'll try to learn as I go.

Comment: If T is your matrix where does it send $\left( \begin{matrix}
   1  \\
   0  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$ and $\left( \begin{matrix}
   0  \\
   1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$? Then $$T\left( \begin{matrix}
   x  \\
   y  \\
\end{matrix} \right)=xT\left( \begin{matrix}
   1  \\
   0  \\
\end{matrix} \right)+yT\left( \begin{matrix}
   0  \\
   1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$$

Comment: Exactly, what Paul says. You can  consider what a matrix looks like by thinking about what it does to your basis vectors.

Comment: Shouldn't there also be a $T$  on the right side though?

Comment: Fair point! Edited

Comment: Following the algorithm gives me the answer 5/13 12/13 -12/13 -5/13. Is this correct? @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo

Comment: Need a "-" sign on the first 12 is all.

Comment: @Paul Oh yes. That's right. Thanks.

Comment: Let $a_1$ be an orthonormal vector in the direction of the line, then for any vector $v_1$ we obtain the orthogonal reflection by: $v_1- 2 (v_1 \cdot a_1) a_1$ for our first vector this is $(1,0)- 2 ( (1,0) \cdot  \frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}(2,3)) \frac{1}{ \sqrt{13}} (2,3)= (1,0)- \frac{4}{13} (2,3)=(\frac{5}{13}, -\frac{12}{13})$ Exactly as you found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that vectors on this line have  the form $(1, -\frac{2}{3} )$, and an orthogonal vector would be $(\frac{2}{3}, 1) $. A very straightforward procedure could be to reflect the vectors $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ orthogonally in this line. Have you done this before? Once you have determined the images of the basis vectors, you can figure out what the matrix columns should look like.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the comment above (which requires a bit of trig), where does your matrix T send $\left( \begin{matrix}
   3  \\
   -2  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$ and $\left( \begin{matrix}
   2  \\
   3  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$ which are on and perpendicular to your line respectively. Now can you find a and b in terms of x and y so that $$\left( \begin{matrix}    x  \\    y  \\ \end{matrix} \right)=a\left( \begin{matrix}    3  \\    -2  \\ \end{matrix} \right)+b\left( \begin{matrix}    2  \\    3  \\ \end{matrix} \right)$$ Finally, apply T to find T$\left( \begin{matrix}
   x  \\
   y  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$